# Set row names of matrices in an array

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, r-rownames

I have an array consisting many 2*3 matrices.

I want to give same row names to both rows of each matrix in my array. I'm trying `dimnames()`, however I'm not getting what I want.

```
c1a <- c("1a","1a","1a")
c1b <- c("1b","1b","1b")
c2a <- c("2a","2a","2a")
c2b <- c("2b","2b","2b")
c3a <- c("3a","3a","3a")
c3b <- c("3b","3b","3b")
df1 <- as.data.frame(rbind(c1a,c2a,c3a))
df2 <- as.data.frame(rbind(c1b,c2b,c3b))

my.arr <- simplify2array(unname(Map(rbind, asplit(df1, 1), asplit(df2, 
1))))

dimnames(Y)[[1]] <- c("a", "b")
```

Comment: Please include reproducible sample data (e.g. using `dput`). It's not clear to me what you're trying to do.

Comment: It's `dimnames`, with a "s".

Comment: and it's `list("row1", "row2")`

Answer (score 2):

Use `apply` over 3rd dimension -

```
apply(my.arr, 3, function(x) {rownames(x) <- c('a', 'b');x}, simplify = FALSE)

#[[1]]
#   V1   V2   V3  
#a "1a" "1a" "1a"
#b "1b" "1b" "1b"

#[[2]]
#   V1   V2   V3  
#a "2a" "2a" "2a"
#b "2b" "2b" "2b"

#[[3]]
#   V1   V2   V3  
#a "3a" "3a" "3a"
#b "3b" "3b" "3b"
```

Answer (score 2):

We could just do this with `dimnames`.  There is no need for any looping

```
dimnames(my.arr)[[1]] <- c('a', 'b')
```

-output

```
> my.arr
, , 1

  V1   V2   V3  
a "1a" "1a" "1a"
b "1b" "1b" "1b"

, , 2

  V1   V2   V3  
a "2a" "2a" "2a"
b "2b" "2b" "2b"

, , 3

  V1   V2   V3  
a "3a" "3a" "3a"
b "3b" "3b" "3b"
```